# Как тестировать сервер nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, circleci

В тестировании локально проблем нет. Я запускаю в одной вкладке консоли сервер,  а в другой `jasmine`. Но как тестировать на `circleci`? В плане того что нужно запустить сам сервер а потом запустить `jasmine`, но если запустить сервер `node server.js` то это заблокирует консоль. Нужно как то запустить сервер чтоб он не блокировал последующую команду запуска тестов.

Comment: Может просто открыть новую вкладку консоли и параллельно после  `node server.js` запускать тест?

Comment: Можно использовать `pm2` и запускать сколько угодно серверов :)

Answer (score 0):

Для тестирования REST API (умышленно не рассматриваю e2e) рекомендую использовать библиотеку [ChaiJS](http://chaijs.com/) в связке с любым загрузчиком тестов (jasmine или mocha). Это позволит развернуть полное окружение тестирования, в том числе и ваше приложение, в одном контексте:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const assert = require('assert');
// Подключаем файл сервера, в нем экспортирован сервер express
const server = require('server.js');

// подключаем should-спек
const should = chai.should();
describe('common test pack', () => {
  it(`GET index}`, done => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get(`/`)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            // проверяем статусы
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Также для анализа тела ответа к ChaiJS-HTTP запросу после звена get (или post) добавьте парсер (либо свой, либо сторонний):

```
chai.request(server)
        .get('/file')
        .buffer()
        // добавляем parser
        .parse(binaryParser)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            // например, мы тестируем partial content
            res.should.have.status(206);
            res.header['content-length'].should.be.equal(`${length}`);
            assert.equal(length, res.body.length);

            done();
        });
```

Код парсера (принимает обычный [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) и функцию обратного вызова):

```
const binaryParser = (res, cb) => {
   res.setEncoding(`binary`);
   res.data = ``;

   res.on(`data`, (chunk) => {
      res.data += chunk;
   });

   res.on(`end`, () => {
       cb(null, new Buffer(res.data, `binary`));
   });
};
```